# iOS Container and Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a ContainerViewController with several ChildViewControllers：

```
ContainerVC
 - ChildVC 1
 - ChildVC 2
 - ChildVC 3
 - ...
```

I'm trying to use Auto Layout for these ChildViewControllers with align vertically. But these ChildViewControllers does not have the fixed height. My current resolution is:

1. Set `preferredContentSize` in ChildViewController
2. Use KVO to observe the `preferredContentSize` of ChildViewController in the ContainerViewController
3. Update constraints when `preferredContentSize` changed

My view of the ContainerVC is a Scroll View ...
Do you have any suggestions? Sorry, I am not a native English speaker ...

Comment: I don't think, your Container View Controller have ChildViewControllers. Probably, they have Child Views. Can you please verify.

Comment: Yes, they each have a view.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using preferredContentSize, you may probably wanna use proportional view sizes for your child views because unless you are having a Scroll view, your view controller has a finite frame size.

Imagine your view controller's frame size is 600 x 600 and now on run time, your 1st view's height turns out to be 250 pt, 2nd view's 350 pt and 3rd view's 200 pt. See, you have a problem as your View Controller can only accomodate 600 pt for all of your views.

So, you probably need to set your views proportionally, so that all 3 views fit inside the frame. Let's say, you wanna allot 25% height to your ChildVC_1, 35% to the ChildVC_2 and rest 40% to the ChildVC_3. Now, all your views fit inside your ViewController. You can achieve this scenario easily with Equal Height Constraint. It is not a good practise to leave your View decide their size unless the container is a scroll view.

So, you may want to think a little different approach.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't say it clearly.  My view of the ContainerVC is a Scroll View ...